# Is this correct coding for prepared statements in php? I have a form with multiple post?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, forms, pdo

I've been trying to get this code to work on inserting to my form but I keep getting one error after another. I'm at my wits end with this and in need of help. I'm new to php and pdo so any help would be greatly appreciated. I've searched this forum and read some books on the issue by my knowledge and understanding is still limited but here are the errors I get and the code.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Rental Form\testdb04.php on line 1455

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){   
$config = array(    
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'dbname' => 'rentalform'
);  

    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['dbname'], $config['username'], $config['password']);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


$filterType = array( 'string' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING | FILTER_SANITIZE_STRIPPED,);


        $post = array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $filter = $filterType[gettype($value)];
    $value = filter_var($value, $filter);
    $post[$key] = $value;
}
$bindValues = $post;


$tenant = implode(',', array_keys($bindValues));
$values = implode(',:', array_keys($bindValues));


$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO rental_form ($tenant) VALUES (:$values)");

foreach($bindValues as $key => $value) {
    $stmt->bindValue(':' . $key, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
}

$stmt->execute();

//echo '<pre>'.var_dump("INSERT INTO rental_form ($tenant) VALUES (:$values)").'</pre>';

/*echo "INSERT INTO rental_form ($tenant) VALUES (:$values)";*/
/*for ($i=0, $c=count($filterType); $i<$c; $i++) {
    echo $filterType[$i];
}*/
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this question cannot be answered because it cannot be read.

Comment: Do you want the syntax error to be fixed (please, why not tell us what that line-number is?), or do you need help with pdo? Probable at least the first one: and that is just you having a syntax error. Multiple I'd say (that `'$_POST[tenant_lname]'` isn't too good. Please use some debugging first. Echo/var_dump your stuff, check if all looks like you want it to look, check your IDE for hints about where you made a type/missed a `;` etc.

Comment: @Nane Which fields for var_dump

Comment: Which line is line 1455?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax error is probably `$post[$key] => $value;` which should use an equal sign not a double arrow like this: `$post[$key] = $value;`.

But you should also take care of [Nanne's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546999/nanne) comment about removing the single quotes from `'$_POST[tenant_lname]'` because even if it doesn't give a syntax error, it will still give wrong values for the array key names, it will be the string `$_POST[tenant_lname]` instead of the value with that key.

**Update**
1) To get rid of the Notice, add an `if isset` to the assignment as below:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($filterType[gettype($value)])) 
    {
       $filter = $filterType[gettype($value)];
       $value = filter_var($value, $filter);
    }
    $post[$key] = $value;
}
```

2) The echo confirmed what I think is the problem which is that merging `$bindValues` and `$post` is giving `$bindValues` inconsistent key types (both Integer and String). What is the purpose of the merge? Because I think that's what is messing up the INSERT statement. Are the values in the original `$bindValues` always the same as the keys in `$_POST`? From the echo, they seem to be. So if yes, then try the below:

```
$tenant = implode(',', array_keys($post));
$values = implode(',:', array_keys($post));
```

**Update2**

Okay, things are pretty clear now. So the issues I mentioned are actually correct in that link but not translated correctly into your code which is why you're having issues.

1) `$bindValues` in the link actually has a different format than yours, it's initialized as `$key => $value` where you just have `$key`. The link used it because they had some keys with manual values. Since your values are completely in $_POST, you don't actually need `$bindValues`, only `$post`.

2) You are using `$filterType` incorrectly. It is meant to have actual PHP datatypes as keys, so you actually only need one record in that array with key 'string'.

Your code should actually look like this:

```
<?
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {   
    $config = array( 'host' => 'localhost', 'username' => 'root', 'password' => '', 'dbname' => 'rentalform' );  

    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['dbname'], $config['username'], $config['password']);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $filterType = array( 'string' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING | FILTER_SANITIZE_STRIPPED );

    $post = array();
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $filter = $filterType[gettype($value)];
        $value = filter_var($value, $filter);
        $post[$key] = $value;
    }
    $bindValues = $post;

    $tenant = implode(',', array_keys($bindValues));
    $values = implode(',:', array_keys($bindValues));

    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO rental_form ($tenant) VALUES (:$values)");

    foreach($bindValues as $key => $value) {
        $stmt->bindValue(':' . $key, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }

    echo "INSERT INTO rental_form ($tenant) VALUES (:$values)";
    $stmt->execute();
  }
?>
```

Let me know what that gives you.

Comment: Not entirely clear on what your saying here. I changed    '$_POST[tenant_lname]'   to    $_POST[tenant_lname]   and received the following errors:    Notice: Use of undefined constant tenant_lname - assumed 'tenant_lname' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Rental Form\testdb04.php on line 1298  also get the following:  Notice: Undefined index: string in C:\xampp\htdocs\Rental Form\testdb04.php on line 1453  the line on 1453 is    $filter = $filterType[gettype($value)];

Comment: error at the bottom of the window reads: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,' at line 1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Rental Form\testdb04.php:1470 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Rental Form\testdb04.php(1470): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Rental Form\testdb04.php on line 1470

Comment: @Nanne my actual form is on top of all the php coding. I wasn't sure to post the entire form or just a part of it so, I posted only the php code. If this isn't  not enough let me know if you need to see the entire form. Over 1500 lines

Comment: Here's a var_dump of ($post = array();    Notice: Undefined index: string in C:\xampp\htdocs\Rental Form\testdb04.php on line 1457
array(152) { ["tenant_lname"]=> bool(false) ["tenant_fname"]=> bool(false) ["tenant_mname"]=> bool(false) ["ssn"]=> bool(false) ["dl_number"]=> bool(false) ["dl_state"]=> bool(false) ["birthday"]=> bool(false) ["tenant_hphone"]=> bool(false) ["tenant_wphone"]=> bool(false) ["tenant_cphone"]=> bool(false) ["curr_street"]=> bool(false) ["curr_unit"]=> bool(false) ["curr_city"]=> bool(false) ["curr_state"]=> bool(false)

Comment: Didn't notice you don't have single quotes around the index name. It should be `$_POST['tenant_lname']`. Let us know what errors you still get after that.

Comment: I'll try that. Are there anymore reports I should post?

Comment: I had changed that already. >    $_POST['tenant_lname'] => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING | FILTER_SANITIZE_STRIPPED,

Comment: used    var_dump($post) and received this error.    Notice: Undefined index: string in C:\xampp\htdocs\Rental Form\testdb04.php on line 1457
array(152) { ["tenant_lname"]=> bool(false)

Comment: this is line 1457.     $filter = $filterType[gettype($value)];     this is the code block.    $post = array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $filter = $filterType[gettype($value)];
    $value = filter_var($value, $filter);
    $post[$key] = $value;
}

Comment: also getting    `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,' at line 1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Rental Form\testdb04.php:1476 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Rental Form\testdb04.php(1476): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Rental Form\testdb04.php on line 1476

Comment: The Notice (Undefined Index) is not critical but it means that the index you're trying to access in the array isn't set. Did you change the single quote placement in all the lines of `$filterType` initialization  ? 

As for the exception, $tenant at this point contains the long list of numbers which is in the error in your last comment(0,1,2...) , I'm guessing you need them to be the actual names like 'tenant_fname' and 'tenant_lname' ?

Can you post the result of this: `echo "INSERT INTO rental_form ($tenant) VALUES (:$values)";` Also can you update your original post with your new code?

Comment: Original post updated. Quote placement in $filterType changed.

Comment: Included post of results: echo "INSERT INTO rental_form ($tenant) VALUES (:$values)"; at bottom of original post. Hope this helps.

Comment: I found where the original coding was posted. Check it out here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/11147/php-prepared-statements with the full explantions. Hope this helps. also I used jQuery Masked input on some of the date fields, and there are check box's in some fields. see the bottom portion of the the original post.

Comment: The radio buttons and date fields shouldn't matter if you want to treat all the fields as String. Please check Update2 in my original answer.

Comment: Okay I used the latest code you posted and now I'm getting errors upon opening the page. Before I didn't get errors until after I clicked the submit button. Page opens but errors listed at the bottom of page. Not sure what's happening now. I posted your new code beneath the code in my original post. Also the following fields will need to be encrypted. But that's a little later once the form starts to function properly. "ssn","checking","checking_bal","saving","saving_bal","checking1","checking_bal1","saving1","saving_bal1","credit_acct","credit_bal","credit_payment","credit_acct1" ect...

Comment: What's that line at the end of the code? `> 'localhost', 'username' => 'root', 'password' => '', 'dbname' => 'rentalform' ); [...]` Is that in your page? Because that's probably what's giving the error on page load.

Comment: That's what comes up when the page has loaded, located on the bottom of the page. Not in the code. Some type of error.

Comment: As the error says, the column 'submit' is not found. You should do `unset($_POST['submit']);` before `foreach($_POST as $key => $value)`. Are all the other keys in `$_POST` valid columns in table `rental_form`? If not, you need to unset any invalid keys like you did for `$_POST['submit']`.

Comment: $post = array();
  unset($_POST['submit']);
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $filter = $filterType[gettype($value)];
    $value = filter_var($value, $filter);
    $post[$key] = $value;
} I believe all other keys are valid.

Comment: New error code:      Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Rental Form\testdb07.php:1313 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Rental Form\testdb07.php(1313): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Rental Form\testdb07.php on line 1313

Comment: Wow! figured that one out. Had to change field in DB as autoincrement. Everything is working so far like a charm. You are certainly a genius RMK. Thank you for all your help and support. Now I'm on to encrypting some of the data fields upon submittal. I hope you'll be around for that one. Thank you once again. I couldn't have done it without you.

Comment: one more thing, Having problems connecting to my remote server. Connects fine using:  $hostname = "Abcd.ef.1234567.myhost.com";
    $username = "Abcdef";
    $password = "A1234";
    $dbname = "stuff";


 $con = mysql_connect("$hostname","$username","$password");
if (!$con){
die ("Can not connect:" . mysql_error()); 
}

mysql_select_db("stuff",$con);

Comment: wont connect using:        $config = array( 
 'hostname' => 'Abcd.ef.1234567.myhost.com',
     'username' => 'Abcdef',
     'password' => 'A1234',
     'dbname' => 'stuff'

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['hostname'] . ';username=' . $config['username'], $config['password'], $config['dbname']);

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'pdoDbException' with message 'Access denied for user 'A1234'@'111.111.11.111' (using password: YES)' in /home/content/11/11111111/html/testdb07.php:1311 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/content/11/11111111/html/testdb07.php on line 1311

Comment: Glad the first part worked. Can you open a new question with the new problem and link it here? Since this issue is resolved and the comments are lengthy now.